# TypeError: $(...).on is not a function

Tags: jquery, cakephp-1.3, lightbox

I am using [jQuery litebox](http://sandbox.tse-webdesign.be/lightbox-print/). After adding JS and CSS files I got this error TypeError:

```
$(...).on is not a function at this line in js file                                           
 "return  $('body').on('click',       
'a[rel^=lightbox], area[rel^=lightbox]', function(e) {"
```

Can anybody help me to understand the problem here?

I am doing this implementation in CakePHP 1.3.

Comment: You did include jQuery version 1.7 or newer, and you did wrap your code in document.ready right ?

Comment: Yes i have added jquery 1.7

Comment: i havent implement any code for lightbox yet, if i just add js and css files i got this error

Comment: @user1613870: So you're saying that the code you've quoted isn't yours? Where did it come from, then?

Comment: @Crowder that code is from lightbox.js, the library i am using, on this line i am get error

Answer (score 60):

The problem may be if you are using older version of jQuery. Because older versions of jQuery have 'live' method instead of 'on'

Answer (score 31):

The usual cause of this is that you're *also* using Prototype, MooTools, or some other library that makes use of the `$` symbol, and you're including that library after jQuery, and so that library is "winning" (taking `$` for itself). So the return value of `$` isn't a jQuery instance, and so it doesn't have jQuery methods on it (like `on`).

You can use jQuery with those other libraries, but if you do, you have to use the `jQuery` symbol rather than its alias `$`, e.g.:

```
jQuery('body').on(...);
```

And it's usually best if you add this immediately after your `script` tag including jQuery, before the one including the other library:

```
<script>jQuery.noConflict();</script>
```

...although it's not *required* if you load the other library after jQuery (it is if you load the other library first).

Using multiple full-function DOM manipulation libraries on the same page isn't ideal, though, just in terms of page weight. So if you can stick with just Prototype/MooTools/whatever or just jQuery, that's usually better.

Comment: Crowder, thanks for you guidelines, i am not adding any library before jquery, all the libraries have been added after jquery library. i am using this technique <?php echo $html->css ( 'skin/lightbox.css', 'stylesheet' ); ?> and <?php echo $html->script(array('libs/lightbox'), array('inline' => false)); ?>

Comment: @user1613870: As I said, if you're including another library **after** jQuery (like Prototype or MooTools), you'll have this problem. (Not if you put them in *before*; if you did them *before*, you'd have a different problem.) Are you using Prototype or MooTools?

Comment: noConflict did nothing for me... but jQuery('body').on(...); FIXED the problem ... thanks! Will know now :)

Answer (score 12):

This problem is solved, in my case, by encapsulating my jQuery in:

```
(function($) {
//my jquery 
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Can you please explain what do you mean by `my jQuery`? do you mean it `jQuery version x.x.x` or `jQuery cycle.all` or the script you are writing ?

Comment: I think he meant the script and yes encapsulating my script around that function actually solved my problem

Answer (score 5):

If you are using old version of jQuery(< 1.7) then you can use "bind" instead of "on". This will only work in case you are using old version, since as of jQuery 3.0, "bind" has been deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the solution of Oskar (and many others) but for me it finaly only worked with:

```
jQuery(function($){
   // Your jQuery code here, using the $
});
```

See: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/

Comment: You're a legend given my scenario. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In my case this code solved my error :

```
(function (window, document, $) {
            'use strict';
             var $html = $('html');
             $('input[name="myiCheck"]').on('ifClicked', function (event) {
             alert("You clicked " + this.value);
             });
})(window, document, jQuery);
```

You don't should put your function inside 
 $(document).ready