# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).on is not a function

Tags: jquery, drupal, drupal-7

Suddenly after we added some new code/features.. we get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).on is not a function
```

Our code is clean and works as a stand-alone html/js/css project.

We tried upgrading to the latest jQuery vrsn : jquery-1.11.0.min.js
and we're still getting this error. GRR!

What else can we do to troubleshoot this?

*Running: Drupal v7*

thanks so much!

- i already tried all these suggestions here: [TypeError: $(...).on is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15670352/typeerror-on-is-not-a-function)

Comment: what was your previous jQuery version. If it was below `1.9.0` then you should check whether you are loading `JQuery Migrate Plugin` plugin along with `jQuery 1.11.0`

Comment: Please check this below url, it will help you to fix the issue.
http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/129952/jquery-on-method-returns-undefined-is-not-a-function

Comment: For me, it was because my Adminimal theme was using jQuery Update, but that particular theme was set to Drupal's default jQuery version (1.4). Setting the theme to 1.10 fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

After a closer inspection we found 2 vrsns of jquery running.
http://screencast.com/t/2qr2Cv09oWP
 * we inherited this project.

Solution was this: https://www.drupal.org/project/jquery_update

Answer (score 0):

1. you should download and setup jquery_update module on drupal.
2. you should run your function reverting the $ alias
3. pay attention to the way you insert code in drupal_add_js function

**update:**
as I can read from the error description you already followed the second point.