# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).affix is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting JavaScript error:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).affix is not a function

I have loaded all JS on my view page in this order

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/presents/shawnee/designs/javascripts/libs/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/presents/shawnee/designs/javascripts/libs/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/presents/shawnee/designs/javascripts/libs/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/presents/shawnee/designs/javascripts/libs/jquery.lazyload.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/presents/shawnee/designs/javascripts/libs/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/presents/shawnee/designs/javascripts/libs/jquery.placeholder.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/presents/shawnee/designs/javascripts/libs/googleDirections.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/presents/shawnee/designs/javascripts/libs/scripts.js"></script>
```

Here is the affix code

```
// Sticky navbar desktop only 
$('#navbar-fixed').affix({
    offset: {
      top: function() {
        return (this.top = $('#masthead').outerHeight(true) + $('#navbar-fixed').height());
      }
    }
  })
// For a subpage called 'tools'. Creates sticky sidebar 
$('#tools-sticky-nav').affix({
  offset: {
    top: function() {
      return (this.top = $('#masthead').outerHeight(true))
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: `$.append` maybe?  What are you trying to do?

Comment: actually in scripts.js file I have a function that uses affix functions from bootsrap.min.js file so and I have also loaded all the functions before the scripts.js file but it always gives me uncaught error.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include any additional information you have to your question. Avoid adding this in the comments, as they are harder to read and can be deleted easier. The edit button for your post is just below the post's tags.

Comment: Are you sure `bootstrap.min.js` gets loaded correctly? Have you checked your network tab?

Comment: @h2ooooooo yes because I have checked the view source page and found that it is loaded

Comment: are you using ajax of any kind?

Comment: I remember running into this kind of problem when resetting affix via ajax calls

Comment: also, is affix included in your bootstrap.min.js could it be that you did not include the plugin if you build a customized bootstrap.min.js file with limited resources? from here ... http://getbootstrap.com/customize

Comment: I would assume from the message that the affix plugin is not present in your bootstrap.min.js!

Comment: Further if affix is included, it could be a jQuery conflict issue, as such: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15670352/typeerror-on-is-not-a-function

Comment: I have used this cdn https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js

Comment: When you said "I have checked the view source page and found that it is loaded" are you saying that you viewed the source and clicked the link to the JS file and it loaded?

Comment: @j08691 yes, Apart from that I have also used the CDN link maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js  to load the js.

Comment: you can also check the demo site http://shopshawneemall.red5demo.com/sales  check it on firebug...!!

Comment: Have you tried removing the `defer`?

Comment: You're loading jQuery twice (2.2.0 and 1.7.1) - this might very well destroy your definition of `$` and reset it which is why `$.affix` does not exist (as 1.7.1 is loaded *after* you've loaded this file). If this is on purpose please read [Can I use multiple versions of jQuery on the same page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566595/can-i-use-multiple-versions-of-jquery-on-the-same-page).

Comment: update bootstrap.js to version 3.0 and it working
[https://stackoverflow.com/a/44344544/1673050](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44344544/1673050)